# stored procedure vs anonymous block - same data, different results

Tags: database, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I am having trouble getting my head around different results I get when running the same code using anonymous block and stored procedure. They both take some details from data dictionary, but it looks like the stored procedure cannot pull full data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testing IS
    lv_schema VARCHAR2(10) := 'some_schema';
    total NUMBER;
    CURSOR tab_cur IS 
      SELECT    table_name
              , column_name
      FROM    all_tab_columns 
      WHERE   OWNER = lv_schema;
    in_record tab_cur%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    total := 0;
    OPEN tab_cur;
    LOOP
      FETCH tab_cur INTO in_record;
      EXIT WHEN tab_cur%NOTFOUND;
      total := total + 1;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE tab_cur;
    dbms_output.put_line(total);
  END testing;
```

For my own schema it gives me correct results (small schema, finds 13 results). For one of our smaller apps it gives incomplete result (50, instead of expected 83), while for another one (big) it lists 0, instead of 5181).

I have dismissed the idea this is because of privileges (I can view all the results correctly when I query data dictionary directly with SELECT), and thought it may be size-related (cursor failing when there is too many results, dunno), but I get all correct results when I run the very same code in anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
  lv_schema VARCHAR2(10) := 'some_schema';
  total NUMBER;
  CURSOR tab_cur IS 
    SELECT    table_name
            , column_name
    FROM    all_tab_columns 
    WHERE   OWNER = lv_schema;
  in_record tab_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  total := 0;
  OPEN tab_cur;
  LOOP
    FETCH tab_cur INTO in_record;
    EXIT WHEN tab_cur%NOTFOUND;
    total := total + 1;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE tab_cur;
  dbms_output.put_line(total);
END;
```

The only changes here being "DECLARE" instead of "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing IS" and removal of function name from END line... Anyone could point me towards some explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: cursor *failing*? how? Do you get an error?

Comment: no, no, no error, sorry for the misunderstanding. Both pieces of code execute without any apparent error, they just give different result.The idea of cursor not being able to retrieve large amount of data (what I incorrectly described as 'failing') is grasping at straws, I know...

Comment: the list shown by all_tab_columns depends on the privileges given to the user. Check that and let me know if it doesnt work out.

Comment: I checked this again, the SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_tab_columns WHERE OWNER = 'some_schema' gives me correct counts. Both those selects and anonymous blocks were executed by my DB user, as well as the stored procedure (it was created and executed with the same user account by me).
Thanks for taking time to help me out!
... but I think you may be onto something - the partial result I got, the 50 out of 83, showed all columns for two tables, but none for other few... But how may privilege for one account impact anonymous block and stored procedure differently...?

Comment: Roles will be active in the anonymous block but not in a definer-rights procedure, so differences in the `all_*` views are to be expected.

Comment: Gents, I think William Robertson has a point - I read up a little (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authorization.htm; search for 'How Roles Work in PL/SQL Blocks')
I tried using DBA_TAB_COLUMNS, asn A Techtown suggested, but the access to both those data dictionary tables is granted from the roles, so even though I seem to have an answer as to why this all happens, I am still looking for some remediation strategy.
Thanks to all involved!

Answer (score 4):

[William Robinson's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974203/stored-procedure-vs-anonymous-block-same-data-different-results#comment69158743_40974203) pointed me to a solution.

Here is a relevant quote from [*Configuring Privilege and Role Authorization*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authorization.htm) in the Oracle documentation:

> #### Roles Used in Named Blocks with Definer's Rights
>
> All roles are disabled in any named PL/SQL block (stored procedure,
>   function, or trigger) that executes with definer's rights.

My access to data dictionary table used (`all_tab_columns`) was granted through a role. That is why it was not taken into account when I ran the query in a stored procedure. The solution here is to create a procedure and force it to use invoker rights rather than definer rights (which is the default) by using the `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` clause when creating the procedure.

Comment: It's more about your access to the tables themselves than to the all_tab_columns view. Say HR grants select privilege on `EMPLOYEES` to role `HR_READONLY`, which SCOTT has. The `all_` views take roles into account, so SCOTT will see `EMPLOYEES` listed in `all_tables` etc when querying on the command line or in an anonymous block, but not from inside a definer-rights procedure, where only directly granted privileges count.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.I think it is related to privilege .

Below is additional clause in ALL_TAB_COLUMNS which is not there in DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.

```
and (o.owner# = userenv('SCHEMAID')
    or
    o.obj# in ( select obj#
                from sys.objauth$
                where grantee# in ( select kzsrorol
                                     from x$kzsro
                                   )
              )
    or /* user has system privileges */
      exists (select null from v$enabledprivs
              where priv_number in (-45 /* LOCK ANY TABLE */,
                                    -47 /* SELECT ANY TABLE */,
                                    -397/* READ ANY TABLE */,
                                    -48 /* INSERT ANY TABLE */,
                                    -49 /* UPDATE ANY TABLE */,
                                    -50 /* DELETE ANY TABLE */)
              )
   )**
```